# Bootstrap dropdown not working when I append it with <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im having trouble with my bootstrap dropdown. it is not working when I append it with div. and cloned the 1st one.. I want to show again the bootstrap style but the bootstrap style is not working

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {


      var max_fields = 8; //maximum input boxes allowed
      var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap1"); //Fields wrapper
      var add_button = $("#add_field_button1"); //Add button ID
      var x = 1



      //initlal text box count
      $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click

            e.preventDefault();
            if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
              x++; //text box increment


              <? php $wqeqw = 1;
              while ($wqeqw <= 8) {

                $wqeqw++;
              } ?>


              $(wrapper).append("<div>" +
                  "<select  name='item_packing[]'  data-placeholder='Click here to select' multiple class='form-control chzn-select  chzn-rtl' tabindex='10'>" +
                  "<option value='AAA'>AAA</option>" +
                  "<option value='BBB'>BBB</option>" +
                  "<option value='CCC'>CCC</option>" +
                  "<option value='DDD'>DDD</option>" +

                  "</select>" +  // Incomplete Code . OP has to update this part
```

HTML

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap1">

  <select style="height:12350x;" name="item[]" data-placeholder="Click here to select" multiple class="form-control chzn-select  chzn-rtl" tabindex="10">
    <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
    <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
    <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
    <option value="DDD">DDD</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="add_field_button1" class="btn btn-success" onclick="fetch_select1();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add Another Item</button>
```

Comment: Could you provide the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You have already initialized

var add_button = $("#add_field_button1");

add the click event without the $

```
add_button.click(function(){
});
```

and the same for

change $(wrapper).append() to wrapper.append();

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to find what a problem is first , remove everything maybe in ur document.ready function and only put ur append code...if it doesnt work then u will know that the problem is in the append line,narrow the scope of problem to that level first